# Objection on artificial moon for lighting

Tags: the-moon, artificial-satellite

Some days ago i read about [China's artificial moon mission for lighting cities](http://www.astronomy.com/news/2018/10/china-artificial-moons)

In my junior classes i was taught the effect of Moon's gravity on tidal waves.

According to me this is a very dangerous mission this can cause floods due to additional gravitational force.

Am I wrong?Please explain.

> I had searched on Internet about this defect of China's artificial moon for lighting but i didn't found any result.Many astronomers are against this mission as this will disturb natural timing of flora and fauna.But no one has raised the point ,that it will disturb natural motion of tidal waves.

Comment: [Tsunamis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunami) are *not* caused by the Moon's gravity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been called ["fake news"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/chengdu-fake-moon-news-eric-bretschneider/) However tides are caused by gravity, and the proposal doesn't seem to require very massive satellites, hence no tidal waves.

Answer (score 3):

The "Artificial Moon" which is being proposed is not nearly as close a copy of the real moon as your concerns suggest. It will be smaller, closer and probably hollow, whereas the real moon is a rather large solid ball of rock quite a long way away. In particular the artificial moon would not be massive enough to exert significant gravity.